# Prepopulate Django AutoCompleteSelectField

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, autocomplete

I'm trying to prepopulate a custom form's field with JS after DOM has finished loading. Correct values get filled into the form field, but when I submit the form Django throws me 'This field is required' error. I'm guessing it has something to do with it being AutoCompleteSelectField instead of a regular CharField.

Here's the form field in question:

```
country = AutoCompleteSelectField (
    label = _('Country'),
    lookup_class = CountryLookup,
    widget = AutoCompleteSelectWidget(CountryLookup, attrs = {
        'class': 'span12',
        'required': 'True',
    })
)
```

And here's the JavaScript:

`$('#id_country_0').val(myObject.country);`

Comment: From which app you're using `AutoCompleteSelectField`? There are different django apps holding the same field implementation. Also it's better if you post your lookup class code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be that you are passing a null value for a attribute which is required in database .

TO check this what you can do .

use   `print form`  in your respective views

and check the result in track back of python .There you will get which filled is required that you are not passing .

This is just a way to debug this problem .Then update your post .

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, that was/is an excellent way to debug. It appears that AutoCompleteSelectField had a hidden required field attached to the form that wasn't getting the correct value from $('#id_country_1').val('CountryCode')